# postUpdate, postRemove, postPersist - is the data in the database yet?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

For the purposes of the question I'll ask about `postUpdate` but I'm assuming they're all analogous. If I fetch an existing entity, modify it, and then flush, then I can subscribe to a `postUpdate` event about this. At the point that this event fires, is the data actually in the database yet? Or there a tiny amount of time in between the event firing and the data actually being saved still?

The docs seem to clearly say that

> The postUpdate event occurs after the database update operations to entity data

so from that I'd assume the former.

But I'm encountering a problem similar to [Symfony 2 postUpdate executed before data is stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369961/symfony-2-postupdate-executed-before-data-is-stored) - where the answer suggests that it's because during a `postUpdate` event the data is not actually fully saved yet, and that's what the `postFlush` event is for instead.

Can someone confirm either way please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behaviour occurs because all post* events are triggered inside transaction block (expect postFlush), so the datas are actually in the database already but they are in transaction which is not yet commited.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, they run after the database transaction has started but before it's been committed - so the answer is no, the data isn't in there. `postFlush` runs after the transaction is committed